# Save product-attribute value

Tags: magento2, product-attribute, phtml

***How to save attribute value into DB from a phtml ?***

*ie, Phtml contains a custom input field which is rendered in the admin product edit page under a custom tab.*

The value entered in the input field should be saved in an attribute which already created by admin